# Parameterize Tests to run Parallel or Single Thread in MSTEST

Tags: multithreading, parallel-processing, mstest, video-recording

My scenario is that we want to run test on devops multithreaded. Mainly things should run and pass..So no pngs or video is needed to record.

BUT, say we have issues, I have a runsettings file that has the  to record videos. It seems to have folders for every test that has run, but only the main window that is displayed is actually being recorded. So, my solution to this is to turn off the Parallelize option for the tests. To see if the video recorder can only start and stop on each individual tests. How would I change that setting based on the runsetting files...how can I turn that off at the application level. Or how do I successfully record video for each test run in parallel.

Comment: Can you show us the RunSettings file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found another way to do it. During the devops process, after checking out the code, I am doing a bit of powershell, which is below. Then only a singular tests run at a time.

```
task: PowerShell@2
  inputs:
    targetType: 'inline'
    script: |
      (Get-Content -Path '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\code\properties\AssemblyInfo.cs') |
            ForEach-Object {$_ -replace 'Workers = 0','Workers = 1'} |
            Out-File '$(Build.Repository.LocalPath)\code\properties\AssemblyInfo.cs'
    errorActionPreference: 'continue'
```